# Typescript tsconfig filsGlob not copy to the root of app folder

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to compile and copy all ts files from `dev` folder to `app` folder.
So what I want is copy all compiled files to the root of app folder, like `app/app.component.js`, but currently, the result is `app/dev/app.component.js`

How can I achieve this?

Here is my current tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "outDir": "./app"
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "./dev/**/*.ts",
    "!./node_modules/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ],
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the "rootDir" option?

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html